# LWC if:true not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-templates

This platform is beautiful when it works, super frustrating when it doesn't. Any ideas? For some unknown reason I can't get the template to skip the branch when false, it is always rendering...

**template**

```
showSubmitButton = {showSubmitButton}
<template if:true={showSubmitButton}>
    <li class="slds-item">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_9-of-12 slds-medium-size_10-of-12 slds-large-size_3-of-12 ">
                <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Submit"  title="Submit" onclick={handleSubmitClick}></lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</template>
```

**javascript**

```
@api showSubmitButton=false;
connectedCallback() {
    console.log(`bw: showSubmitButton = ${this.showSubmitButton}`);
}
```

**call to the component**

```
<c-test show-submit-button="false"></c-test>
```

**console result**

```
bw: showSubmitButton = false
```

**page result**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/js_props_boolean)

> NOTE Setting show="false" evaluates to true. The only way to specify false in markup is to omit the boolean attribute.

You can do this in your callback:

```
    if(this.showSubmitButton === 'false') {
        this.showSubmitButton = false;
    }
```

or you can omit the variable from the parent itself.
and it should work.

If you really want to set the attribute dynamically then you need a getter in you parent component like this :

```
<c-test show-submit-button={computedValue}></c-test>
```

---

```
get computedValue(){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was driving me crazy!